# Success ajax request and if statement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with ajax in symfony4. I want to treat an apply function (apply for an offer) with jQuery and Ajax I have this function in the controller.

The process execute as expected I mean when I click on the button (apply) for the first time the offer concerned will be stored with the right data. and if it's not the first time it won't be stored (that's correct).

```
     /**
     * it allows any user to Apply for an offer and create a new applyOffre object in the applyOffre table
     * @Route("candidat/offre/{id}/apply", name="offre_apply")
     * @param OffreEmploi $offre
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     * @param ApplyOffreRepository $applied
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function apply(OffreEmploi $offre, EntityManagerInterface $manager, Request $request, ApplyOffreRepository $applied)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $apply = new ApplyOffre();
        $appliedOffre = $applied->findAll();
        $exist = false;
        $temps = array();
        $idx = 0;

            if($appliedOffre and !$exist) {
                foreach ($appliedOffre as $applie) {
                    if ($applie->getOffre() ==$offre and $applie->getCandidat() ==$user) {
                        $exist = true;
//                        $this->addFlash('warning', ' you've already applied for this job ');
                    }
                }
            }

        if(!$exist)

        {
            $apply->setOffre($offre)
                ->setCandidat($user);
            $manager->persist($apply);
            $manager->flush();
            $temps[$idx++]=array(
                '$offre'=>$offre,
                '$user'=>$user
            );
           // $this->addFlash('success',' it's done a new apply registered ');

        }

        return new JsonResponse($temps,200);
    }
```

but all the problem is on the alerts.if the job is applied for the first time an alert " Postulé " will appear and if it's not an alert "Deja postulé" supposed to appear .for the moment I have just the "postulé" alert which appears when the offer is applied for the second time (even that the method in the controller is executed correctly). This is the Ajax/jQuery related to this function:

```
  $("a.js-apply").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url=this.href;
        var b=this.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data, status) {

                if (data) {
                    $(this).slideToggle('fast', function () {
                        $('a#' + b).text('Postulé');
                        alert('postulé');
                    });
                }
                else{
                    alert('deja postulé');
                }
                // alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Ajax request failed.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the data argument in the success function.  Testing for

```
if (data)
```

will return true even if the data is an empty JSON array.

The solution is to change the if statement to

```
if (data.length > 0)
```

Comment: yes it was that, it was very simple think you very much ):